# Unity crashes when try to insert ImageTarget

Tags: vuforia, unity-game-engine

I'm try to create a simple virtual reality project in Unity 5 with Vuforia 5 SDK on a Mac. I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.justapixel.co.uk/how-to-make-an-ar-app-in-5-minutes-with-unity-and-vuforia/).

Right now I'm stuck on the part where I try to insert the `ImageTracker` from the `Vuforia -> Prefabs` folder into the scene. Whenever I try to do that, the Unity program crashes.

Why is it crashing? Is there anything I can do to work around or diagnose that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems like Vuforia is not compatible with Unity 5.3.2 and 5.3.3 (that's the one I had). You need to revert Unity back to 5.3.1. That did the trick for me!

Vuforia Notice: 
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/notice-unity-532-incompatible-vuforia

Unity forum : 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/latest-unity-vuforia-builds-crashing-on-imagetarget-import-into-scene.384068/

Answer (score 0):

Moving back to Unity 5.3.1 solved this error for me.